# Monorepo with Jenkins and Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, node-sass

My issue is that I have a Dockerfile.Build which is running lerna bootstrap on a monorepo project. The Docker instance is running centos:7.

The monorepo has 31 packages. When I run lerna bootstrap it is reinstalling the node-sass binrary on each package within the repo.

Has anyone come across this before / has anyway to avoid the binaries being reinstalled on each install?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For monorepos and jenkins you can use the changeset, only build/deploy if some specific somefolder/file has changed.

Comment: @marxmacher the way its setup at the moment it has symlinked dependencies so we build all packages in order to be able to use it in the other e.g. our eslint package is used in our components package, so both need to be created.